# Python performance increase

Tags: python, performance

I wrote a python script and will start this script like 10000 times with different inputs and I noticed it takes quite a while in the actual structure:

```
def MCMC(DepT,Dur,Dep,Arr):    
#Get data from list
with open('GaR5.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if Dep in line:
            DepTZ=float(line.split('\t')[2])
            DepRat=float(line.split('\t')[3])
        if Arr in line:
            ArrTZ=float(line.split('\t')[2])
            ArrRat=float(line.split('\t')[3])
    tZ=DepTZ-ArrTZ
    from numpy import sin
    import math
    from scipy import integrate as intg
    def CalcJetlg(x):
          return(((intg.quad(lambda z: sin(z * math.pi / 8 + (-math.pi/2 -    12 * math.pi / 16)), x, x+Dur))[0]))    
         #[0] true integral, [1] Fresnel sine signal
    iT=(round(float(1-(CalcJetlg(DepTime)+(-5.1))/(-10.2)),2))
    oT=(round(float(1-(CalcJetlg(DepTime+tZ)+(-5.1))/(-10.2)),2))    
    if(TzDiff<0):
        resR=(iT*0.8+oT*0.2)
    else:
        resR=(1-(iT*0.8+oT*0.2))    
    APRat=((1-(DepRat/119))+(1-(ArrRat/119)))/2
    return(round(float(resR*0.8+APRat*0.2),2))

import sys
DepT=float(sys.argv[1])
Dur=float(sys.argv[2])
Dep=str(sys.argv[3])
Arr=str(sys.argv[4])
print(MCMC(DepT,Dur,Dep,Arr))
```

The GaR5.txt looks like this:

```
1   GKA 10.0    120
2   MAG 10.0    120
3   HGU 10.0    120
4   LAE 10.0    120
5   POM 10.0    120
6   WWK 10.0    120
7   UAK -3.0    120
8   GOH -3.0    120
9   SFJ -3.0    120
10  THU -4.0    120
```

And I would run the script like this in windows shell
**python MCMC.py**

I noticed an execution like this takes like 1 second, when I start it in the Spyder iPython console it takes just 0.02 seconds,what could be a good approach in order to speed up this script?

The main thing I found is that starting it from shell takes so much longer than running it in iPython, is there any faster way to run the script? It has to be run via shell given the other coding I have

Comment: Have you tried profiling it or measuring the performance in any way? What did you find? Was there something specific you need answered You're basically dumping a bunch of code into SO and expecting someone to fix it for you which is not what the for or very good at.

Comment: Thank you for your comment pvg, I added one sentence to make the question more clear. It is mainly about another way to start or run the script as the shell execution takes like one second and within iPython console it just takes 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Wouldn't the difference between 1 second and 0.05 second be the difference in starting the interpreter? You shouldn't be using it in a loop that creates and destroys an instance of the interpreter 10000 times.

Comment: Can you fix the indents? I'm not sure if `def CalcJetlg(x):` is supposed to be nested in the first function.

Comment: I ran a trimmed down version that just does the imports. Time on my (admittedly slow) machine was .5 seconds. Loading python without the extra imports was .08 seconds. That's the base cost of doing business in python on my machine.

Comment: @ tdelaney def CalcJetlg(x) just basically consists of the next line. Is there really no way to speed up this process? As I would run this script 10.000 times it would take more than 2h

Comment: There's always going to be some overhead to starting a new process, initializing the interpreter, parsing your code, etc. The shorter the execution time of your code is, the more noticeable this overhead is going to be. You can try generating a .pyc file for your script and see if it helps any but the fundamental solution is to not run short bits of code by launching a new interpreter over and over, if you care about performance.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do with the non-Python code. What language is it in? Perhaps there is some way to let Python be in overall charge, and have the non-Python code controlled by the subprocess module. I can't believe that spawning 10,000 instances of the interpreter is really unavoidable.